# algorithm for extracting high and low values from range of db recs

Tags: php

I have a data structure like this:

```
 array (size=10)
   1 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/05/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '11:13' (length=5)
   2 => 
    array (size=2)
    'fdate' => string '11/05/12' (length=8)
    'ftime' => string '11:13' (length=5)
   3 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/05/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '11:50' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/05/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '11:51' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/07/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '09:11' (length=5)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/07/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '09:12' (length=5)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/07/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '10:29' (length=5)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
     'fdate' => string '11/08/12' (length=8)
     'ftime' => string '11:06' (length=5)
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
    'fdate' => string '11/08/12' (length=8)
    'ftime' => string '11:06' (length=5)
  10 => 
    array (size=2)
    'fdate' => string '11/08/12' (length=8)
    'ftime' => string '11:07' (length=5)
```

I need to evaluate and end up with the first and last ftime values for each date, in this case

```
 fdate     ftime1 ftime2
 11/05/12, 11:13, 11:51
 11/07/12, 09:11, 10:29
 11/08/12, 11:06, 11:07
```

I have a loop like this:

```
 $struct = array();
 $i = 1;
 foreach($recs as $row){            
   $struct[$i]['fdate'] = $row->fdate;// store fdate
   $struct[$i]['ftime1'] = $row->ftime;// store initial ftime
   $currentfdate = $row->fdate; // use $currentfdate in comparison to $row->fdate

   if($currentfdate <> $row->fdate){
      $struct[$i]['ftime2'] = $row->ftime;// store last ftime
   }

   $i++;
 }
```

I am not sure how to determine when the fdate changes to trigger the storing of ftime2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($recs as $row){            
   $temp[$row->fdate][]=$row->ftime;
}

foreach($temp as $date=>$value){
  echo $date.'-'.current($value).'-'.end($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit naive, in the sense that it assumes your recordset is already ordered properly (meaning the same dates are adjacent to each other and that their times are sequentially ordered ascending):

```
<?php

$records = array(
    array( 'fdate' => '11/05/12', 'ftime' => '11:13' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/05/12', 'ftime' => '11:13' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/05/12', 'ftime' => '11:50' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/05/12', 'ftime' => '11:51' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/07/12', 'ftime' => '09:11' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/07/12', 'ftime' => '09:12' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/07/12', 'ftime' => '10:29' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/08/12', 'ftime' => '11:06' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/08/12', 'ftime' => '11:06' ),
    array( 'fdate' => '11/08/12', 'ftime' => '11:07' )
);

$struct = array();
$currentDate = null;
$i = 0; // if you want zero-indexed result, change this to -1
foreach( $records as $record )
{
    if( $currentDate <> $record[ 'fdate' ] )
    {
        $i++;
        $struct[ $i ] = array(
            'fdate' => $record[ 'fdate' ],
            'ftime1' => $record[ 'ftime' ]
        );
        $currentDate = $record[ 'fdate' ];
    }
    else if( $struct[ $i ][ 'ftime1' ] <> $record[ 'ftime' ] )
    {
        $struct[ $i ][ 'ftime2' ] = $record[ 'ftime' ];
    }
}

var_dump( $struct );
```

*(replace array notation to object notation for your needs.)*